# Find the monthly count, for every month from the start date till member is cancelled

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Problem: Monthly distinct count of members from the first date of the gene reading, till the member is cancelled.

Members can have more than one reading per month. They can continue to have as many readings as they want.

Example:

```
member_id    date       gene_a_measurement_done    gene_b_measurement_done
5557153     1/1/2010    y                      
5557153     2/1/2010                                y
222458      2/1/2010    y                           y
222458      1/1/2011                                y
707222      1/1/2011    y
```

Another table has members cancellation date:

```
member_id    status      date    
5557153     Cancelled    5/1/2011           
222458      Cancelled    12/1/9999      
707222     Cancelled     12/1/9999
```

Expected result :

```
month    distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_a_measurement      distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_b_measurement    
1/1/10              1                                       0
2/1/10              2                                       2
3/1/10              2                                       2
4/1/10              2                                       2
5/1/10              1                                       1
6/1/10              1                                       1
7/1/10              1                                       1
8/1/10              1                                       1
9/1/10              1                                       1
10/1/10             1                                       1
11/1/10             1                                       1
12/1/10             1                                       1
1/1/11              2                                       1
```

Query tried:

```
SELECT 
    sub.last_day,
    sum(sub.distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_a_measurement) as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_a_measurement,
    sum(sub.distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_b_measurement) as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_b_measurement,
FROM 
    (SELECT last_day(date),
            COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_a_measurement,
            null as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_b_measurement,
    FROM  measurement
    WHERE gene_a_measurement_done is not null
    GROUP BY    last_day(date)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  last_day(date),
            null as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_a_measurement,
            COUNT(DISTINCT member_id) as distinct_count_of_member_with_gene_b_measurement,
    FROM  measurement
    WHERE gene_b_measurement_done is not null
    GROUP BY    last_day(date)) as sub
GROUP BY    sub.last_day(date)
```

Above query only gives distinct count of member for the month for which measurement was done and I am not sure how to best consider cancellation date? (inner join with member_status table on member_id and have condition to filter out cancelled member?)

Comment: Why distinct count? Can members sign up measurement more than once a month? And why cancellations? Do members sign up measurement beyond cancellation date? Also, where's your SQL query that you tried that does not work?

Comment: @Parfait Distinct count because a member can have more than one reading a month(have modified the question). Cancellation because member can cancel from the medical report program and we don't have consider those member in the count. Members would not have measurement beyond cancellation date, however, if they had measurement in the first month (for example) then they will be counted as having measurement till the cancellation month. Will post the query that gives distinct count per measurement area, don't know how to cover the months for which don't have data and cancellation date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Amazon Redshift. Sorry for the confusion. Have modified the question.